# Cannot start dropbox due to "pantheon-filechooser-module" error

Tags: linux, dropbox, elementary-os

I cannot solve the issue. When I start dropbox, I get an error:

```
Starting Dropbox...Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I searched for a solution in the internet, but didn't success.

OS: Elementary OS Freya 0.3

Comment: I think this answer could help you.
[http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/339/1248][1]


  [1]: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/339/1248